# Call a python script from a PHP script

Tags: php, python

I have written a python script (mail.py) to send email in python, and I have written another file to submit action. I need that the file `mail.py` should run in background. when I am writing the follwing code

```
$result=shell_exec('python mail.py&');
                echo $result;
```

then there is no response but when i am running the file `python mail.py &` then it is running successfully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set full path to python's interpreter like:

```
 shell_exec('/usr/bin/python mail.py &');
```

Comment: how can i check that this command is running in background or not. because still it is not sending any mail but sending using command line

Comment: @lord_linus you can't using shell_exec. other methods include interprocess communication with mail.py, checking pid of mail.py, or make mail.py write a log and the read that log with php

Comment: hey now mail is being sent but I am getting one problem that I am doing two task: one is to submit the form and display some data and another is to send a mail in background. but when i am clicking to submit the form then it is waiting for sending the mail. but i need that the data should be displayed first and it should not wait for send mail

Comment: @VladBalmos whats the problem in sheel_exec()

Comment: shell_exec returns only the output of the command after it has executed. You are executing the ptyhon script in background, thus shell_exec returns imediatly without providing any output. So you can't know for sure if execution was successful or not